# Set or change Converter using a trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

Here is my TextBox with a converter:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding TimbraturaSelezionata.OrarioMinuti, Converter={StaticResource Minuti2HHmmConverter}}" Margin="5,0"/>
```

I searched for a way to set or change the converter only when it is effectively needed.
In fact I would like to put that TextBox inside a general purpose User Control and apply the converter only when a specific condition is met.
The only solution that came to my mind is to use a **ContentControl** and use two **DataTrigger** to set its template, one with the Converter inside the TextBox, and one without. I would hope finding a clearer way to achieve my goal.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: why don't you pass a parameter to the converter?

Comment: It is a possibility, but I would prefer the trigger, if I find how to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're set on a trigger. Here's an example. Hope it helps;

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding TimbraturaSelezionata.OrarioMinuti}" Margin="5,0">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <ei:DataTrigger Value="False"
                      Binding="{Binding YourCondition, ElementName=MyTextBox}">
          <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text"
                                   Value="{Binding TimbraturaSelezionata.OrarioMinuti}" />
      </ei:DataTrigger>
      <ei:DataTrigger Value="True"
                      Binding="{Binding YourCondition, ElementName=MyTextBox}">
          <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text"
                                   Value="{Binding TimbraturaSelezionata.OrarioMinuti, Converter={StaticResource Minuti2HHmmConverter}}" />
       </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution is the folowing:

```
<TextBox  Width="100">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding   ValoreInMinuti}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Quantita, Converter={StaticResource Minuti2HHmmConverter}}" />    
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding   ValoreInMinuti}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Quantita}" />

                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

Note that the Text property is set only via DataTrigger. In my specific case I had only two possibilities, one with the converter and one without it.

Comment: Ah right sorry, was apparently thinking SL not WPF with my example, same concept though. Cheers! :)